# Specifying a destination path while creating a zip

Tags: linux, zip

Let us assume I have a zip file called patch.zip, when I run `unzip -l patch.zip` I get the following output.

bin/a
bin/b
lib/c

To this zip file I want to add a new file, "Readme.txt" located at /path/to/Readme.txt in such a way that, when I re-run `unzip -l patch.zip` again I get something like this

bin/a
bin/b
lib/c
doc/Readme.txt

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to specify the pathname files should have within the zip-file, so you can't say "store /var/tmp/Readme.txt" as doc/Readme.txt".

You would have to create the directory layout on disk first, as a sort of staging area:

```
mkdir doc
cp -p /path/to/Readme.txt doc
zip foo.zip doc/Readme.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I just recreate the zip file. I know it might not be the solution you need, but it is a very simple solution. I've also found issues with messing with zip file contents while still compressed so found this method to be more reliable.